# How can I change row height from cellForRowAtIndexPath?

Tags: swift, uitableview, height, row, cell

I need to change row height in **cellForRowAtIndexPath**, using UITableView.

heightForRowAtIndexPath executes before cellForRowAtIndexPath, but in cellForRowAtIndexPath I'm settings content to rows, depended on which height must be recalculated.

Comment: How are you setting the content of the rows?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't, the only place you can and should change is `heightForRowAtIndexPath`
But there are other solutions for you problem, that are explained very well  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746929/using-auto-layout-in-uitableview-for-dynamic-cell-layouts-variable-row-heights)

I encourage you to check third solution whitch enable Row Height Estimation.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the height in the **viewDidLoad**  for all cells

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 88.0
```

or use the event **heightForRowAt** where u have the **IndexPath** for the cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
       return 88.0
}
```